# SUBSTR inside a where with Zend DB v1

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I am doing a query with Zend DB (v1) but I can't find a way of include a SUBSTR statement on the query because have multiple parameters.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM myTable
    WHERE SUBSTR(myField, myVar1, myVar2) = 'xxx'
```

I need to use the Zend DB standard format but where does not seems to accept more than one parameter while I need to pass myField, myVar1, myVar2 as PHP variables ($myField, $myVar1, $myVar2). 'xxx' is not a variable here, is a fixed value.

```
    $sql = $this->select()
        ->from(["t1" => "myTable"]])
        ->where( ... ); // Not sure how to implement this
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try and error I found this workaround that seems to work:

```
$myFieldQuoted = $this->_db->quote($myField);
$myVar1Quoted  = $this->_db->quote($myVar1);
$myVar2Quoted  = $this->_db->quote($myVar2);

$sql = $this->select()
    ->from(["t1" => "myTable"]])
    ->where("SUBSTR($myFieldQuoted, $myVar1Quoted, $myVar2Quoted) = 'xxx'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just write it!

```
 $sql = $this->select()
        ->from(["t1" => "myTable"]])
        ->where("SUBSTR(myField, myVar1, myVar2) = ?", 'XXX')
```

Comment: Thanks but I am afraid that it will not solve my problem as myField, myVar1, myVar2 are coming as PHP variables while 'xxx' is a fixed text. As they need to be escaped it will not work. I edited my question to clarify what I need..